# Access url using shell script

Tags: shell, command-line

How to access url (http://www.localhost:8080) using shell script not in browser.  I just want to run my app server and test

Ex. sh example_test.sh

I tried like this `wget localhost:8080/myproj?ce=1234` but it saying Cannot write to `myproj?ce=1234' File name too long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try following

```
content=$(wget http://localhost:8080 -q -O -)
echo $content
```

Or

```
content=$(curl -L http://localhost:8080)
echo $content
```

Comment: Hi .. Thanks alot.. I am newbie to shell script. wget works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Two most popular command line tools:

- curl
- wget

Comment: Hi I tried like this wget http://localhost:8080/myproj?ce=1234        but it saying Cannot write to `myproj?ce=1234'    File name too long